# Browse windows network with Thunar

Tags: networking, windows, xubuntu, smb, thunar

I have a clean installation of Xubuntu 17.10 but when I open Thunar and try to "browse network." I get an error that says "failed to retrieve share list from server. Connection timed out."

The other computer on my home network is running Windows 10.
My router is an Asus RT-N66U

I looked for other questions like this one on here but none of them looked very recent, and I don't know how much has changed with recent versions or Xubuntu or Windows since then.

Is there anything I can do to be able to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself by changing some settings in Windows 10. In the "add or remove windows features" controls, I noticed that SMB was not activated. I activated it, rebooted the windows machine and was then better-able to connect via my xubuntu laptop.